# What is the simplest way to get GCR image digest through terraform?

Tags: docker, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

Terraform GCR provider has data source called [`google_container_registry_image`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/data-sources/container_registry_image) which has an argument [`digest`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/data-sources/container_registry_image#digest), but it will be null since it is stated that data source works completely offline.

```
data "google_container_registry_image" "image" {
  project = "foo"
  name = "bar"
  tag = "baz"
}
output "digest" {
  value = data.google_container_registry_image.image.digest // this is null
}
```

Current workaround I use uses docker provider and looks like this:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    docker = {
      source = "kreuzwerker/docker"
      version = "2.11.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "docker" {
  registry_auth {
    address = "gcr.io"
    config_file = pathexpand("~/.docker/config.json")
  }
}

data "google_container_registry_image" "image" {
  project = "foo"
  name = "bar"
  tag = "baz"
}

data "docker_registry_image" "image" {
  name = data.google_container_registry_image.image.image_url
}
output "digest" {
  value = data.docker_registry_image.image.sha256_digest
}
```

Using two providers and additional docker credentials seems pretty complicated for such a simple use case, is there some easier way to do it?

Comment: Hey, I have the same issue. Did you find a fix?

Comment: Unfortunately nothing prettier than the workaround I've written above

Comment: Hmm yeah. I tried using your method, but terraform cloud doesn't have a docker host on the container that is executing the plan/apply. So I had to make use of an external provider and bash script to get the image digest :)